# How to view math symbols at this url

Tags: html, mathjax, mathml

I see lines like the following at https://plotly.com/python/v3/alpha-shapes/

Let $S$ be a finite set in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d=2,3$ (i.e. a set of 2D or 3D points).

What is it? MathML or embedded latex or something else? Do I need an extension to view it?
I have already tried chrome, edge, firefox, opera on windows.
I looked at the html of the page I see use of the term mathjax.

Comment: FWIW, I also only see the markup (that is, not the intended result) in the latest version of Firefox (109.0.1, 64-bit) on Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is it? MathML or embedded latex or something else?

It's LaTeX embedded.

> Do I need an extension to view it?

You shouldn't need anything, the server should do the rendering.
Many markdown flavours (but neither Github nor SuperUser do) and CMS know that syntax, often with help of [Katex](https://katex.org/) or [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/). Unfortunately, here, [Potly Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/introduction) did not do it directly.
Authors should check how to [include the needed JS+CSS](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources) so you (the readers) have a better experience with their pages.

Comment: FWIW: Firefox 109 on Ubuntu 20.04 displays it, no extras required.

Comment: Replying with 109.0.1 (64 bits) on Mac OS X here, and things like `$\mathbb{R}^d$` aren't converted (and I'm happy the HTML is respected.) Check if you don't have some nifty extension @Hannu Maybe [TeX.Zilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/texzilla/)?

Comment: I found that strange behaviour weird… It's certainly a bug on Ubuntu's version (I'll check some other platforms later)